# text detection in unordered text with yolo and east

Tags: ocr, yolo, yolov5, yolov8

I’m now trying to make best text detection model for ocr. But my purpose is to detect text which doesn’t have any sequence pattern. It’s all unordered letters. So for this situation does the text detection model needs to be heavy model? Object detection might need many features but english letter is only 26 letters.

Now i’m doing with east, yolov3, yolov5, yolov8.

Comment: How did you get on with this task since your question? Can you share your findings?